# When UIButton content mode is "center," background image is pixelated

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Here's how I'm setting the background image and content mode:

```
[btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dots_game_horiz_blue.png"] 
               forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn setContentMode:UIViewContentModeCenter];
```

Is there a reason that the background image would be pixelated? The frame is slightly larger than the image size, and I just want the image to be centered.

Comment: Sorry, to drag that up from the depths of time, but there is a memory leak in there, if I am not mistaken. No release for the alloc.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I guess a background image is not considered to be "content" by the UIButton, so the content mode did not apply to the background image. Instead, I set the image of the button and it worked just fine:

```
[btn setImage:[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"dots_game_horiz_blue" ofType:@"png"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn setContentMode:UIViewContentModeCenter];
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the UIButton has an internal margin, so if the image is not small enough it will be cropped, even if it should fit inside the button.

Comment: Setting the content mode isn't actually doing anything here.  Button images are automatically centered and not scaled. Try setting it to anything but centered and see what I mean.

Comment: +1 However, unfortunately if you want to have text as well as an image this won't work :-(

Comment: Note that setting the content mode in interface builder doesn't have impact in the preview but will work when you'll launch the code.

Comment: bit of a workaround rather than an actual answer as the question specifically states background image.

Answer (score 10):

In your xib / storyboard, in the Attributes inspector, you need to:

1. Set your `UIButton` type to `Custom`
2. Set your image in the property `Image`, not `Background`
3. Validating step 2, you can see the button frame changed according to the image set. Set the frame as you want it to be, the image will resize itself to fit in
4. Select `Image` for the property `Edge` in order to apply inset to the button image
5. Enter inset values you need. If you set 5 to `Top, Bottom, Left, Right`, the image will be centered inside the button, with a border of 5

You can see the changes in the xib / storyboard view, no need to launch a debug.

Tip: Inset is the same for every images of the button (`State Config`)

Comment: Anything that starts with `In your xib / storyboard` isn't a solution for this question :D

Comment: By now, the solution evolved. You can skip the step 4 and go with step 5 through the size inspector (rule icon).

Answer (score 5):

You could also implement `- (CGRect)backgroundRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds` to control how the background is drawn.

Comment: This worked for me. I make a custom UIButton class, and I used this code to center the image: `- (CGRect)backgroundRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
 UIImage *bkgImage = [self backgroundImageForState:self.state];
 if (bkgImage) {
  CGFloat x = floorf((self.bounds.size.width-bkgImage.size.width)/2);
  CGFloat y = floorf((self.bounds.size.height-bkgImage.size.height)/2);
  return CGRectMake(x, y, bkgImage.size.width, bkgImage.size.height);
 }
 else return [super backgroundRectForBounds:bounds];
}`

Comment: "Overkill" solution imo. You can simply set frame for button such as:
UIImage* img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dots_game_horiz_blue.png"]; 
[btn setBackgroundImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width, img.size.height);

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution is to change the type from System to Custom. Then the background image will honor the content type instead of just centering. In my case I set it to Aspect Fill and apply a 45 degree corner radius to round it. Simple and works perfectly.

Comment: This doesn't work. I created a new custom button and set its content mode to Center, but it still fills the background image to the size of the view.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to create rounded buttons for avatar photos and found the answers to this question to help but they did not get me all of the way there. I implemented the `backgroundRectForBounds` method and scaled the image to fit and it works well.

I have the code on GitHub.

https://github.com/brennanMKE/CircleButton

The method is also listed below. It is important to set the background image and not the image for the button which does not work with this method.

```
- (CGRect)backgroundRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    UIImage *backgroundImage = [self backgroundImageForState:self.state];
    if (backgroundImage) {
        CGFloat maxWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.frame);

        CGFloat xDelta = maxWidth / backgroundImage.size.width;
        CGFloat yDelta = maxWidth / backgroundImage.size.height;
        CGFloat delta = xDelta > yDelta ? xDelta : yDelta;

        CGFloat x = floorf((self.bounds.size.width - (backgroundImage.size.width * delta)) / 2);
        CGFloat y = floorf((self.bounds.size.height - (backgroundImage.size.height * delta)) / 2);

        return CGRectMake(x, y, backgroundImage.size.width * delta, backgroundImage.size.height * delta);
    }
    else {
        return [super backgroundRectForBounds:bounds];
    }
}
```